# Excel VBA Protect worksheet but allow copy

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using Excel 2010 and protect using the following line in VBA:

```
Worksheets("GL Codes").Protect Password:="xxxxxxxxx", AllowFiltering:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True
```

However, I now receive an error when I double-click to run the below:

```
Range("A" & Target.Row).Copy Destination:=Range("A2")
```

How do I protect but still allow a copy via VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Sorted it!

Just removed the 'locked' protection checkbox for cell A2

Comment: Hi Michael, please edit your answer to add more explanation so that anyone else can easily understand the solution in future